# Unable to load libuv in windows server 2012 r2?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

In visual studio code, I issue dnx kestrel in command line palette.
But I am encountering an error like this

```
info    : [Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.DataProtectionServices] User
profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\myaccount\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProt
ection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to load libuv.
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv.Load(String dllToLoad)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.KestrelEngine..ctor(ILibraryManager librar
yManager, IApplicationShutdown appShutdownService)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.ServerFactory.Start(IServerInformation ser
verInformation, Func`2 application)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.Start()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly,
 String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host, String
 applicationName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly,
 String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment
env, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, Framewo
rkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, FrameworkNam
e targetFramework)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How do I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use kestrel on `win2012` ? You'd better use `IIS` or `AspNet selfhost` instead. `Kestrel` should be use on `Linux` or `Mac`

Comment: `libuv`is part of `node.js`did you try to install node.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kestrel use libuv an asynchronous I/O library. So, you could install it to use Kestrel as web server, or you could use dnx web to launch your app, where web is a command in project.json.

```
"commands": {
"kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --config hosting.ini",
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --config hosting.ini"}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why do you want to use kestrel on win2012 ? You'd better use IIS or AspNet selfhost instead. Kestrel should be use on Linux or Mac

Oh so there's a thing called self-hosting? thanks [@agua from mars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2940908/agua-from-mars) for that info

Comment: Nope. Kestrel will still be used to run .Net 5 with IIS. IIS will act just as a proxy, by using this module: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler. 

More info here: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69